# How to loop over records and then search into another table and if not found then insert it after fetching records from another table in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 3 tables in my data base 
[image: Table 1]
[image: Table 2]
[image: Table 3]

I need to take each id from table1 and need to look in table2 if it is present then do nothing other wise for that Id I need to look into table3 if i am able to find it then fetch the phone number and along with the details from table 1 insert it into table2 .How to do this in oracle ?

Comment: This should be done in a single SQL command. SQL works with data sets; don't think of it like row-by-row iteration. Write a single SQL statement that would say "insert insert into table_2 data from table_1 and table_3 where table_1.id is the same as table_3.id and table_1.id is not in table_2.id"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=4791105773662bc5925d90bccfe709d0)

```
INSERT INTO table_2
SELECT table_1.id, table_1.name, table_1.gender, table_1.age, table_3.phone_num
FROM table_1
INNER JOIN table_3 ON table_1.id = table_3.id
WHERE table_1.id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM table_2);
```

Comment: Will this not add duplicates also if it is already present into it ?

Comment: the where clause here will only insert table_1's id when the id is not present in table_2, so no duplicates if that makes sense to you.

Comment: oh makes sense , i missed it actually... thanks buddy

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `MERGE` statement to avoid accessing `Table2` twice:

```sql
MERGE INTO table2 dst
USING (
  SELECT t1.*, t3.phone_num
  FROM   table1 t1
         LEFT OUTER JOIN table3 t3
         ON (t1.id = t3.id)
) src
ON (src.id = dst.id)
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT (id, name, gender, age, phone_num)
  VALUES (src.id, src.name, src.gender, src.age, src.phone_num);
```

If you also wanted to update the existing rows then you can do it in the same statement:

```sql
MERGE INTO table2 dst
USING (
  SELECT t1.*, t3.phone_num
  FROM   table1 t1
         LEFT OUTER JOIN table3 t3
         ON (t1.id = t3.id)
) src
ON (src.id = dst.id)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE
  SET name      = src.name,
      gender    = src.gender,
      age       = src.age,
      phone_num = src.phone_num
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT (id, name, gender, age, phone_num)
  VALUES (src.id, src.name, src.gender, src.age, src.phone_num);
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=9b152fb397299875f3ffd3221f6d6635)*